# Como executar uma rotina periodicamente de forma automática em um servidor java como o wildfly10

Tags: java

Em um sistema java web, necessito de tempos em tempos que o servidor de aplicação rode uma rotina de forma automática (Scheduler).
O problema é que não sei nem por onde começar, ou seja como fazer o servidor rodar essa rotina sem a interação de um usuario.

Se alguém puder me dar um direcionamento? Qual tecnologia pesquisar, framework...
agradeço.

Hoje não utilizo EJB,  utilizo JSF com primefaces 6 em um servidor wildfly 10.  Spring somente o security.

Qualquer exemplo é bem vindo.

Comment: Está utilizando Spring?

Comment: Você pode criar um bean usando a anotação [@Schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) se estiver usando EJB. Se for este o caso e desejar um exemplo você pode atualizar a pergunta.

Comment: Hoje não utilizo EJB,  utilizo JSF.  Spring somente o security. Qualquer exemplo é bem vindo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

servidor wildfly 10 é basedo em RedHat. utilize o crontab para executar tarefas periódicas
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na verdade estou utilizando no windows. Mas a aplicação vai rodar na nuvem. Não vou ter acesso ao Sistema Operacional.

Comment: mas se vai rodar na nuvem vc tem um painel de controle não tem ? o crontab é este que eu t passei na ss

Comment: E que ainda não estou na fase da nuvem... Não tem como fazer isso direto em Java ou pelo servidor de aplicação?

Comment: tem dos 2 jeitos mas em java vc vai ter de deixar um processo rodando comendo memória. se o seu servidor de aplicação for windows use o agendador de tarefas se for linux vale o crontab mesmo mas por linha d comando.